# how to "add participants" for private youtube video using youtube api

Tags: node.js, youtube, video-streaming, private, live

I am trying to stream video using the [Youtube api](http://support.google.com/youtube/answer/157177).

I want to stream video in [private](http://support.google.com/youtube/answer/157177) mode.

Here is my code for the same

```
`const {google} = require('googleapis');
var OAuth2 = google.auth.OAuth2;
var oauth2Client = new OAuth2(
     //CLIENT_ID
    //CLIENT SCRETE
    // YOUR_REDIRECT_URL
);

oauth2Client.setCredentials({
    access_token: //access token,
    refresh_token: //refresh token

});


oauth2Client.refreshAccessToken((err, tokens) => {

});


const youtube = google.youtube({
    version: 'v3',
    auth : oauth2Client
});


broadcastParams = {

    "part": "snippet,status,contentDetails",
    "resource": {
        "snippet": {
            "title": "into the starry sky..",
            //"scheduledStartTime": "2018-03-04T20:50:00.000Z",
            // "scheduledEndTime": "2018-03-03T18:05:00.000Z",
        },
        "status": {
            "privacyStatus": "private",
        },
        "contentDetails": {
            "monitorStream": {
                "enableMonitorStream": true,
            }
        },
        "cdn": ''
    }
};

// TODO watch the auth parameters in broadcasting in the console testing
youtube.broadcast.insert(broadcastParams, function (err, broadcast) {
    if (err) {
        return console.log('Error creating broadcast: ', err);
    }

    console.log('Broadcast = ' + broadcast.valueOf());

});`
```

But I want to add participant's email address so as to make them see the private video which only the added person could see.
If there is any way to do this please help me out.

Thanks in advance

```
  [1]: http://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research I came to know that YouTube's **private** videos require that the viewer have a YouTube account, be signed into that account and have that account added to the video's access list. Its also limited to 50 people only.

And also need to change the *contentDetails* parameter from **monitorStream** to **broadcast stream**. But need to explicitly invite people and there is no other way to invite people using API.

So for most of the case it's preferred to use **unlisted** for the streaming which means person with the link can view the video and It can be embedded in website too.

Comment: 4 years later, the Youtube API docs don't seem to state the 50 person limitation anywhere. I'd appreciate a citation, if one is available.